# Python Pandas Count date by year to establish visit number

Tags: python, pandas, count

I am a little bit stuck on how to accomplish this in python pandas; there is probably a simpler solution that I haven't been able to find on stackoverflow or google.

I have the following dataframe df:

```
Customer_ID | date             | year             | Dollars
ABC           2017-02-07         2017               456
ABC           2017-03-05         2017               167
ABC           2016-12-13         2016               320
ABC           2015-04-07         2015               145
BCD           2017-09-08         2017               155
BCD           2016-10-22         2016               274
BCD           2016-10-19         2016               255
```

It is a simple dataframe but very large. For every customer, I have the date they transacted and how much they spent. I created the year column for my analysis.

```
#ensured data is in date format
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

#year of transaction as per comment from @Andrew L
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

I want to do the following:

- count which visit number this is for the client in their whole transaction history
- count which visit number this is for the client in the year

So I am looking for this output:

```
Customer_ID| date     | year | Dollars |visit# |17visit#| 16visit# | 15visit#
    ABC     2017-02-07  2017   456         3      1         0          0               
    ABC     2017-03-05  2017   167         4      2         0          0
    ABC     2016-12-13  2016   320         2      0         1          0
    ABC     2015-04-07  2015   145         1      0         0          1
    BCD     2017-09-08  2017   155         3      1         0          0
    BCD     2016-10-22  2016   274         2      0         2          0
    BCD     2016-10-19  2016   255         1      0         1          0
```

I don't know where to start, would it be something down the line of groupby and count but on a date?

Any idea or recommendation would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Would strongly recommend not doing this- `df['year'] = df['date'].astype(str).str[:4]`. You should instead do it this way `df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice - changing it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your data:

```
df
  Customer_ID        date  year  Dollars
0         ABC  2017-02-07  2017      456
1         ABC  2017-03-05  2017      167
2         ABC  2016-12-13  2016      320
3         ABC  2015-04-07  2015      145
4         BCD  2017-09-08  2017      155
5         BCD  2016-10-22  2016      274
6         BCD  2016-10-19  2016      255
```

Find the cumulative visit count for each customer by year:

```
df['visit_yr'] = df.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'year']).cumcount()+1
```

We now have "visit_yr"- visit count per year:

```
df
  Customer_ID        date  year  Dollars  visit_yr
0         ABC  2017-02-07  2017      456         1
1         ABC  2017-03-05  2017      167         2
2         ABC  2016-12-13  2016      320         1
3         ABC  2015-04-07  2015      145         1
4         BCD  2017-09-08  2017      155         1
5         BCD  2016-10-22  2016      274         1
6         BCD  2016-10-19  2016      255         2
```

Using this, we can pivot the year into columns (last two digits) while simultaneously replacing `NaN`s with 0's then joining back to `df`:

```
df.join(df.assign(yr_2 =df.year.astype(str).str[2:]+'visit').pivot(columns='yr_2', values='visit_yr').replace(np.nan, 0.0)).drop('visit_yr', axis=1)
  Customer_ID        date  year  Dollars  visit_yr  15visit  16visit  17visit
0         ABC  2017-02-07  2017      456         1      0.0      0.0      1.0
1         ABC  2017-03-05  2017      167         2      0.0      0.0      2.0
2         ABC  2016-12-13  2016      320         1      0.0      1.0      0.0
3         ABC  2015-04-07  2015      145         1      1.0      0.0      0.0
4         BCD  2017-09-08  2017      155         1      0.0      0.0      1.0
5         BCD  2016-10-22  2016      274         1      0.0      1.0      0.0
6         BCD  2016-10-19  2016      255         2      0.0      2.0      0.0
```

Visit count over entire dataset:

```
df['visit'] = df.groupby('Customer_ID').cumcount()+1
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much; I already upvoted it and am now testing it; I knew it had to be something with groupby! Thank You!

Comment: @jeangelj Glad to help!

Comment: @jeangelj Please do accept as answer if this answered your question. Thanks again.

Comment: definitely - just testing it on my large data set; thank you for your patience